# Problem with WHEN - ELSE

Tags: vhdl

I am new in VHDL. The code below doesn't work for some reason. The D0 and D1 are switches and when I added the D1 it stopped working. clk_Centi is pointing to an LED.

```
end if;
end process gen_clk;

    clk_Centi <= clk_Centi_i WHEN D0='0' AND D1='0' ELSE
            clk_Sec_i WHEN D0='1' AND D1='0' ELSE
            clk_Min_i WHEN D0='0' AND D1='1';

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VHDL, you have to take into account every possibilities in a combinatory block for the program to work properly. I think that if you add a line with

```
WHEN D0='1' AND D1='1'
```

It will work again.

Comment: Easier way is to delete the last `WHEN expression` which will then cover all the bases for you.

Comment: When D0=1 and D1=1 (the state I didn't take into account) my output should be -. Is there a way to state this in VHDL?

Comment: Brians solution should work here without having to care about solving this - with D0=1 and D1=1 it will act like D0=0 and D1=1. Or maybe you do not want it to act like this.

Comment: I should match this case as zero as this will be the output of some leds.